# Numpy array precision, how to overcome with search another array

Tags: numpy, sum

I have a numpy program where I need to find the index of a value in array B from a sum from array A - and sadly the precission problems of numpy arrays gives me a problem with that :(

> A = array([0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])
>     B = array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5])
>
> B==0.3
>     array([False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>
> B==sum(A[:3])
>     array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>
> B==sum(A[:2])
>     array([False, True,  False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>
> sum(A[:2])
>     0.20000000000000001
>
> sum(A[:2])
>     0.30000000000000004

How can I be sure to find the value in array B that is the precise sum from array A??

Best regards
Termo

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a general fact of life with floating point arithmetic. It's no different for python lists than for numpy arrays. Basically, don't test for floating point equality using `==`.

Comment: Do a binary search in B with the sum of the values in B and then compare the absolute value of the difference of the value found in the B with the sum from A. You will need to two check two values in B because the sum could be slightly over or under the desired value in B.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/b9f0f1f8b54d0e4cf74ea5e7d80893d66585c4a1  There will be a `numpy.isclose()` function in `1.7`.

Answer (score 1):

You're just seeing the effects of floating point arithmetic.  (The same thing is true if you used a python list instead of a numpy array.)

I'm actually rather surprised that there's not a built-in function to do floating point "close" comparisons in numpy... There's `numpy.allclose` which does it for comparing between two numpy arrays, but it just returns `True` or `False` rather than a boolean array.

Doing this in general is actually a bit tricky.  `inf` will thrown in false positives and false negatives.  Furthermore subtracting two arrays with `inf` or `nan` in them will raise a warning, so we generally want to avoid doing that...

```
import numpy as np

def close(a, b, rtol=1.e-5, atol=1.e-8, check_invalid=True):
    """Similar to numpy.allclose, but returns a boolean array.
    See numpy.allclose for an explanation of *rtol* and *atol*."""
    def within_tol(x, y, atol, rtol):
        return np.less_equal(np.abs(x-y), atol + rtol * np.abs(y))
    x = np.array(a, copy=False)
    y = np.array(b, copy=False)
    if not check_invalid:
        return within_tol(x, y, atol, rtol)
    xfin = np.isfinite(x)
    yfin = np.isfinite(y)
    if np.all(xfin) and np.all(yfin):
        return within_tol(x, y, atol, rtol)
    else:
        # Avoid subtraction with infinite/nan values...
        cond = np.zeros(np.broadcast(x, y).shape, dtype=np.bool)
        mask = xfin & yfin
        cond[mask] = within_tol(x[mask], y[mask], atol, rtol)
        # Inf and -Inf equality...
        cond[~mask] = (x[~mask] == y[~mask])
        # NaN equality...
        cond[np.isnan(x) & np.isnan(y)] = True
        return cond

# A few quick tests...
assert np.any(close(0.300001, np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])))

x = np.array([0.1, np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf])
y = np.array([0.1000001, np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf])
assert np.all(close(x, y))

x = np.array([0.1, 0.2, np.inf])
y = np.array([0.101, np.nan, 0.2])
assert not np.all(close(x, y))
```

Comment: I don't know when it was introduced but numpy1.17 has an `np.isclose()` function that does return a boolean array. The docs on it are [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html).